# Aggregate and sum using Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have two entities:

- Invoices
- Customers

I want to get the sum of invoices grouped by customers.

After reading some web pages, tutorials, and Apple documentation, it is not clear to me what will be the better approach, using Core Data.

The current solution that works for me, is fetching all customers, and for each one, fetch again only the sum of invoices. Even it is working perfectly, I do not like as a definitive solution.

Maybe using the NSExpressionDescription would be a better approach, but really I do not understand it well enough to use it.

I know Core Data is not a database, and in plain SQL this is really easy, but I am using Core Data :-)

Any advice will be appreciate :-)

thanks,

ps. I have the Marcus Zarra Core Data book but can not find a solution/guidance there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your dataset isn't too large, I'd suggest just using something like `[customer valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.invoices.amount"]`. If you'd like to try to have the sum calculated by the database (Core Data uses SQLite as its backend most of the time), have a look at http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/11/nsexpression.html.

Comment: valueForKeyPath works with NSPredicate? In some cases, I want to limit the @sum on some dates

Comment: No, then you have to filter the invoice array first, then apply the sum function.

Comment: And what's the benefit of using your approach ? Currently I'm fetching the values for each customer, filtered by date.

Comment: It may be slightly more elegant, but in principle what you do is just fine.

Comment: ok thanks, so I suppose that there's no easy equivalent of SELECT customer.name, sum(invoice.total) FROM invoices UNION customers ON ... WHERE invoice.date > .... ?

Comment: Right. http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/11/nsexpression.html is as easy as it gets ;-)

Comment: Do you think it's easy NSExpression? As I say in my question, I have to digger more on it before I can use it on what I want :-)